# Stretch a part of background image

Tags: html, css

I have an image which holds multiple flag images:

[image: Flags]

I have a `div` which has the dimensions: `width:100px; height:50px`. I want to stretch each flag to fit into it:

```css
.flag{
      width:100px;
      height:50px;
      background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/famfamfam/flag/icons-390.jpg');
      background-position: 30px 25px;
      background-size: 390px 260px; // actual size of image
    }
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your flag size is 16x11px and you want to present it as 100x50px, you will have to scale your image 100/16 = 6.25 times on the x axis and 50/11 = 4.54 times on the y axis. So you will have:

```
background-size: calc( 390px * 6.25 ) calc ( 260px * 4.54 );
```

Of course that means that you will also have to calculate the `background-position` accordingly. So, for the first flag we'll have:

```css
.flag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/famfamfam/flag/icons-390.jpg');
  background-position: -38px -36px;
  background-size: calc(390px * 6.25) calc(260px * 4.5); // actual size of image
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Which, of course, looks lame but that always happens with stretched images.

Now, if you are really into it, you can use the `image-rendering` property to "fix a little" the rendering for FireFox and Chrome.

```css
.flag {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/famfamfam/flag/icons-390.jpg');
  background-position: -38px -36px;
  background-size: calc(390px * 6.25) calc(260px * 4.5);
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<div class="flag"></div>
```

Comment: vut how you calc the new position `background-position: -38px -36px`

Comment: @AzeemHaider That one, I did it manually, but it is "distance of the flag from the left * 6.25 m distance of the flag from top * 4.5" which in this case is: 6*6.25 , 8*4.5.

Answer (score 0):

use no repeat

```
<div class="flag"></div>


//Style
.flag{
   width:100px;
   height:50px;
   background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/famfamfam/flag/icons-390.jpg');
   background-position-x: 30px;
   background-position-y: 25px;
   background-size: 390px 260px; // actual size of image
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```